# net view (and WNetEnumResource) is not finding anything but the local computer after changing motherboard?

Tags: networking, server-message-block, windows-net-command

I was going to post in StackOverflow but it's more of a network issue than programming issue as I've used `WNetEnumResource()` for years with no problem.

I upgraded my motherboard of my Windows 10x64 system which is a member of a Windows 2008 Domain (SMB1 disabled).  I setup the new NIC (onboard) to use the same static settings (plus set DNS to the Windows 2008 server) as before.

All my existing network shares mapped to drive letters work perfect (have about 5 of them).

I can "dir \server\share" from a command prompt fine.

But when using `WNetEnumResource()` it no longer shows the servers (only my local system).  The prior system was showing them.

Since I didn't see the servers under the Windows Explorer / Network location (I don't recall if they showed there with the old mobo).   I found information on enabling the `FunctionDiscovery*` services; so on the 2008 servers (one domain controller the other used for terminal services), I enabled those services and viola the systems show in Windows Explorer / Network.

However, they still don't show using `WNetEnumResource()` so I tried `net view` from a command prompt and that only shows my local system as well.  No servers.

The IPv4 settings on the adapter have my static IP, the correct default gateway, the correct dns (the windows 2008 domain controller), and NetBIOS over TCP/IP is enabled.

`nbtstat -r` shows the main domain server with my mapped drives under `NetBIOS Names Resolved By Broadcast`

Well now after about 10 to 15 minutes the `WNetEnumResource()` and `net view` are showing the domain server but not the other server.

Any ideas what is going on?

TIA!!